# PHP array values to associative array keys?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Is there a quick/easy PHP function to take the VALUES of an array and create an new associative array from the value mappings? or is this a classic iterate, parse, and add?

Example, source array in `var_dump()` form:

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> string(36) "md5=397f7a7501dfe5f18c1057885d698d5d" 
    [1]=> string(7) "foo=bar" 
    [2]=> string(7) "t=18351" 
}
```

Should be converted to an associative array:

```
array(3) {
    ["md5"]=> string(32) "397f7a7501dfe5f18c1057885d698d5d"
    ["foo"]=> string(3) "bar" 
    ["t"]=> string(5) "18351"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$myArray = array(); // Fill with values in your example
$string_to_parse = implode('&', $myArray);
parse_str($string_to_parse, $result);
var_dump($result);
```

If your array gets much more complex, with duplicate key/value pairs or other situations, this solution might not work.